# MSBUILD AdditionalProperties not respected in teamcity

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have the following piece of master msbuild script which triggers child scripts with the respective properties.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="3.5">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <BuildLabel>0.8.1.2</BuildLabel>
        </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build" >
        <CallTarget Targets="BuildApplication"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="BuildApplication" >
        <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'==''">
            <ProjectToBuild Include="./Application/Application.msbuild">
                <AdditionalProperties>Configuration=Publish - Beta</AdditionalProperties>
            </ProjectToBuild>
            <ProjectToBuild Include="./Application/Application.msbuild">
                <AdditionalProperties>Configuration=Publish - Production</AdditionalProperties>
            </ProjectToBuild>
        </ItemGroup>
        <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)" Properties="BuildLabel=$(BuildLabel);Platform=Any CPU" />
    </Target>    
</Project>
```

While this script works fine on my local as well as the build server, it does NOT work( `$(Configuration)` is not available to child as shown by teamcity logs) when the same build server checks out the code and runs the script.
what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tools version in teamCity was set to default due to which the child scripts were being called using MSbuild 2.0.Changing it to 4.0 fixed it